# If I write out a file in Vim I loose the paste marker `] Is there any way of retaining it?

Tags: file, vim, save, markers

When I am writing a document and press p in normal mode. Then save the document I loose the paste marker. Is there any way of keeping that marker between saves?

Answer (score 2):

1. It's called "mark" (or "bookmark"), not "marker".
2. These are auto-marks, and so some Vim commands are allowed/supposed to change them. In particular, buffer I/O (re-)sets "bracketed" marks to effective line range (normally it's the whole file for `:write` command).
3. Use some other mechanism to jump to location. Maybe `'.`, maybe `ma` / `'a`, maybe `:h changelist`, etc.etc. There are plenty of ways to get the job done. It's upon you which to choose.